# count number of times a value appears in the entire dataset SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to count number of times all the values appear in the entire dataset. So I want a table/output with values - # of times it appears in the dataset. I have used proc sql, proc freq without any luck.

```
data Data1;
input xx yy zz;
datalines;
123 456 234
456 123 345
234 345 123
;
run;
```

Want a table output with 123 - 3, 234 - 2, etc.

Comment: Please do not use images to show data, but include as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option (I think) is to create a dataset that puts all the values in a single column, then you can just run a `proc freq` off that.

```
data have;
input xx yy zz;
datalines;
123 456 456
456 123 234
234 234 123
;
run;

data single_column;
set have;
array vars{*} xx yy zz;
do i = 1 to dim(vars);
all_vals = vars{i};
output;
end;
keep all_vals;
run;

proc freq data=single_column;
table all_vals / out=want;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful